# DROP SEQUENCE not working on MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

Whenever I try to drop a sequence I get the following error:-

> DROP SEQUENCE seq_12129;
>
> DROP SEQUENCE: unable to drop sequence seq_12129 (there are database objects which depend on it)

I have dropped all the tables in the current schema, but I am still getting this error. Is there a way to find out what database object depends on this sequence?

Comment: Are you using SQL Manager?

Comment: I am using shell itself

Comment: try `EXEC sp_fkeys 'seq_12129'`

Comment: Isn't sp_fkeys SQL Server thing? I don't think so monetDB support this.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I didnt realize that you're using monetDB

Comment: I have changed the title to make it clearer.